# HTTP request loop return same value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, request

I'm looping an HTTP request to get value from multiple restful api's based on a leagueId. However even though that `data[tournament].league` in the find query return

```
14
1
2
9
12
8
```

when i try to console `data[tournament].league`in my request it just return

```
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

How come it does not return the above different league id´s

```
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://db');
var Match = require('./app/models/match');
var League = require('./app/models/league');


// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var x = require('x-ray')();
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var async = require('async');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
var router = express.Router(); 



router.get('/get/matches', function(req, res, next){

    var base = "http://URL";

    League.find({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            for(var tournament in data){
                console.log(data[tournament].league);
                request({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: `${base}/api/league/${data[tournament].league}`,
                    json: true
                    }, function(err, response, body) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(data[tournament].league);
                        } else {
                            console.log(body);
                        }

                });

            }
        }

    });

});






app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: Have you tried running the request async?

Comment: I'm going to run another request inside this request statement, how would this look like with async?

Comment: I have added a async example as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your request asynchronously. You can use [this](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. I think the problem exists because the "callbacks" from your request. You are looping over all your items from your `League` collection and basically firing all requests at the same time. This means your loop is probably already finished before the first request was finished.

Instead you should loop over your array, fire a request, wait for the response and then continue with your loop to do the exact same process again until you are at the end of you array from your collection.

I have updated your query + loop with the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. Try the code below:

```
League.find({}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        async.eachSeries(data, function iterator(item, callback) {
            console.log('item', item.league);
            request({
                method: "GET",
                url: `${base}/api/league/${item.league}`,
                json: true
            }, function(err, response, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error for request with league:', item.league);
                } else {
                    console.log(body);
                }
                callback();
            });
        }, function done() {
            console.log('All finished!');
        });
    }
});
```

**A little side note**: I do not know where `${base}` comes from so there might be a mistake in creating the url.

Comment: Thank you, when i run the code it only returns `All finished`? why dont it return anything else in the log?

Comment: @PeterPik Oh there was a mistake. Can you try it again please?

Comment: Works!! if i now want to make another GET request based on the body in the async call, do i then just make another `async.eachSeries` inside this?

Comment: @PeterPik It depends. Are you making a single call inside your request or multiple calls?

Comment: in the current request i retrieve `body.defaultTournamentId` which return 6 id´s i want loop through an url like `${base}/api/matches/{body.defaultTournamentId}`

Comment: @PeterPik Yes. You will need another async. Please note that it will become a heavy function and it will take some time before it finishes. There might be better ways to call the API.

Comment: Well this function will just called from a cronJob and saving data in my mongodb. then i have another route to retrieve matches from my mongodb? isnt this the right approach?

Comment: It's okay but not if you are make a few honderd call's in a minute. The owner of the API might not like that :)

Comment: i think this would be executed 1 time every 30 min

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95129/discussion-between-thomasbormans-and-peter-pik).